# Is C compiler obligated to place a static const in memory?

Tags: c++, c

Is a C compiler obligated to place a static const variable in memory or is it allowed to use it as immediate instruction operand when referenced?

Comment: Your two questions seem pretty much unrelated except that they both happen to involve the keyword `const`.

Comment: I don't quite get why you seem to state a `static const int i = 5` would have external linkage in C

Comment: @tofro static const will not have external linkage, but the default linkage is different in c and c++. const int i = 5; by default will have static linkage in c++ and external linkage in c.

Comment: If you are thinking about non-static linkage, this invalidates the whole point of your question...

Comment: with the compile parameter `-O0`, the variable will be in memory.  With any other optimization level the variable will be part of the code

Comment: Isn't this compiler -dependant? I am not aware of any standard that talks about compiler options

Comment: I'm surprised the question is closed as to me it is extremely precise. The only thing which is not explicitly stated is by whom can the compiler be obligated. But this seems to me rather obvious: the C standard is the only one that can obligate the compiler to do anything. I'd be glad if any of the editors who decided to close this question added any example of what is too broad in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't as long as you do not tell it to otherwise. It can very well use the constant as literal (immediate) values in assembler instructions.

*Telling otherwise* could be

- declaring the const `volatile` (Telling the compiler: "We don't change it, but somebody else could")
- declaring and/or using i.e. dereferencing a pointer to the `const`which is not explicitely `const`

Comment: Plus using its addrss.

Comment: "casting the `const` to a non-`const` somewhere in your program" is not an example of telling otherwise. If it results in an attempt to modify the object, the behaviour is simply undefined. Compilers are under no obligation to allow or support it, and many don't, by placing the object in a read-only memory section.

Answer (score 1):

A C compiler isn't obligated to put *anything* in memory. Even a non-`static` non-`const` variable could be entirely optimised out, as long as the compiler & linker could prove that the object were not to be referenced externally (or that its address is requested internally, e.g. using the `&` operator) and that its value did not depend on any unpredictable circumstances (such as user input).

A modern C or C++ compiler performs such optimisations *aggressively*, which is why the typical low-level "this is how your program works" explanations that come from the poorer introductory textbooks are misleading, and why we discuss the semantics of these languages in theoretical/abstract terms, rather than obsessing over which bits of data are on which chip of RAM when the user hits a button.

For reference on how this optimisation is permitted, look up the "as-if" rule.

Comment: All true, but the question (somewhat intelligently worded) appears to be about the difference in semantics of const between C and C++.  In C++ a const of a basic numeric type has no storage unless its address is explicitly taken - it behaves as a literal constant so can be used in case labels and array dimensions for example, which is illegal in C.  Conceptually at least a C const has storage, even if its address is never taken, and is not interchangeable with a literal (hence C's greater use of pre-processor defined symbols without scope restriction and having implicit type).

Comment: @Clifford Yes, my question is exactly about what you wrote.